Pull in Contact fields from single Opportunity Query
I'm trying to pull a list of opportunities. We have a lookup field on the opp called "CPA_Contact__c" that is an Id in Contact. What I'd like to do is include the Contact.Name in the query results that matches the Id stored in CPA_Contact__c. Is there a way to write a single query that does this? Below is my obviously incorrect attempt to do this.
SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Account.Website, 
    (SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Id = Parent.CPA_Contact__c), 
    CloseDate, Name, 
    Offering_Type__c, StageName, legal_entity_name__c, notes__c 
    FROM Opportunity 
    WHERE CloseDate >= 2023-01-01 AND CloseDate <= 2023-12-31


SELECT 
     CloseDate, Name, Offering_type__c, StageName, Legal_Entity_Name__c, Notes__c,
     CPA_Contact__r.Name
  FROM Opportunity
  WHERE CloseDate >= 2023-01-01 AND CloseDate <= 2023-12-31

Lookup relationship fields are obtained using the form
relationshipName.fieldName

See SOQL reference doc on relationship queries
If the lookup field is xxx__c, then the relationship name is xxx__r

Perfect!! My SOQL is very rusty and I overlooked the relationship concept.
